# How can I manually build an Electron app with only a ASAR file?

Tags: node.js, electron

Okay, so this might seem like a weird question but hear me out. I want to know how to compile an Electron app manually because what I am doing is I am taking the Twitch app ASAR files and I hope to be able to repackage them for usage on Linux as it is cross-platform. I am wanting to do this #1 so I can use the launcher and #2 so I can post a guide for people to follow on how to do it themselves. I am just stuck on this bit because everything points to something like Electron Packager which requires that I have the source and the build enviroment.

Answer (score 3):

As asar is just a tar like packaging you can easily extract the files with the according environment. Just install asar with `npm install -g asar` and unpack the whole archive with `asar extract app.asar destinationfolder`.

I do not know the Twitch app, but make sure that it has a License which allows altering and redistributing the code. Especially when it comes to filehandling, notification or other native OS things you may have to change some parts of the code to work under Linux.